# Excel report using python pandas for historical data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to generate an excel report using python pandas.
I have json data for the customers like below and "id" is unique.

```
customer_day1 = [{"id": "1","name": "John","ip": "10.1.1.1"},
                 {"2": "Peter","name": "ip": "10.1.1.2"}]
customer_day2 = [{"id": "1","name": "John","ip": "10.1.1.10"}, 
                 {"3": "Nancy","name": "ip": "10.1.1.3"}]
```

Want to generate excel report with below details

1. Highlight new customer rows
2. Highlight deleted customers
3. Highlight customers have changed values between the two dates

Need to identify the differences of 2 date's data and generate a report with above mentioned details.

Comment: I don't think this is good practice. You may need to store the data into database first and then you can fetch the data based on date and find out. Or you will have to add new column in your data called "Date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to find the difference using pandas dataframe. Reference http://pbpython.com/excel-diff-pandas.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def report_diff(x):
    return x[0] if x[0] == x[1] else '{} ---> {}'.format(*x)

def has_change(row):
    if "--->" in row.to_string():
        return "Y"
    else:
        return "N"

customer_day1 = '[{"id": "1","name": "John","ip": "10.1.1.1"},{"id":"2", "name":"Peter", "ip": "10.1.1.2"}]'
customer_day2 = '[{"id": "1","name": "John","ip": "10.1.1.10"},{"id": "3", "name":"Nancy", "ip": "10.1.1.3"}]'

df1 = pd.read_json(customer_day1)
df2 = pd.read_json(customer_day2)
df1.set_index('id',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('id',inplace=True)

df_panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=df1,df2=df2))
df_output = df_panel.apply(report_diff, axis=0)
df_output['has_change'] = df_output.apply(has_change, axis=1)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Report_1.xlsx",engine='xlsxwriter')
df_output.to_excel(writer,"report")    
writer.save()
```